# jquery select remove option

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using this successfully to remove an option

```
    $("select#select_gender option[value='initial']").remove();
```

Is there a way remove an option without adding to the selector - like below?

```
    $('select#select_gender').val('initial').remove();
```

thx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$("select#select_gender option").filter("[value='initial']").remove();
```

I believe that does it.

or per your latest comment:

```
var sel = $("select#select_gender");
sel.find("option[value='initial']").remove();
```

PS sorry for so many edits :(

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
$("#select_gender").children().filter(function(index, option) {
    return option.value==="initial";
}).remove();
```

If you wanted, you could turn it into a plugin, like so:

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.option=function(value) {
        return this.children().filter(function(index, option) {
            return option.value===value;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then you could use this:

```
$("#select_gender").option("initial").remove();
```

**You can demo it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DetuN/).**

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can restrict it down to the option tags

```
$("select#select_genter option").find("[value='initial']").remove()
```

and then for diffenet vals

```
var beg_string = "[value='",
    end_string = "']",

while ( ) {
    /* loop through a list of values */
    $("select#select_genter option").find(beg_string + val + end_str).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do it? You can do something like

```
$('select#select_gender').each(function(a,b){
    if ($(this).val() == 'initial'){
       $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

but **I DO NOT RECOMMEND IT**. Use that first one. It's perfect and easy

Comment: have my well used selectors in variables so I wanted to just reference the variable name... eg: variable.('option').remove(); don't need to re-find the selector... was interested to see if it was possible... I might leave it as is...