# remove the (o)th/(n) th option in dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, removechild, html-select

Can anyone explan me how to remove (0) th/ (n) th element in dropdown menu ?

```
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
   <option value="option1">option1</option>
   <option value="option2">option2</option>
   <option value="option3">option3</option>
   <option value="option4">option4</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: read : http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery select remove option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375491/jquery-select-remove-option)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.eq()`:

```
$('#selectBox option').eq(2).remove();  // Removes the third item
```

Answer (score 2):

This way you can remove option based on its value

```
$("#selectBox option[value='X']").remove();
```

You can also remove option by Text:

```
$("#selectBox option:contains(Text)").remove();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sB6p2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try out this

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DetuN/13/)

```
$("#selectBox option:nth-child(2)").remove();
```

you can replace 2 by any other number i.e. number of option element.

Check how this work : [**:nth-child() Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

**Note :** Option number start from 0 to n ...so be carefull if you write 3 than it removes 2 item in list as it start from 0.